# Is it possible the multiLoad call override an attached and already changed object on the session?

Tags: hibernate

I cannot find anything regarding how this new feature exactly works.
I'm using Hibernate 5.2.17

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
             .byMultipleIds(Product.class)
             .multiLoad(ids.stream()
                           .distinct()
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "override"? Entities that are already in the session will be unchanged by a query and will be returned just the way they are in the session.